# Eloquent relationship between user roles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating an app where users have different roles.  Some of the roles include:

- Administrator
- Supervisor
- Contractor

I have the following tables setup:

- `user`
- `role`
- `role_user`

The `role_user` is a pivot table used to store the `user_id` and `role_id`.

Now, when a *Contractor* is created, I trigger an event which assigns the user to the *Contractor* role in the database:

```
$user->roles()->save($role, ['cust_id' => $event->user->cust_id]);
```

The above line basically just creates a new row in the `role_user` pivot table and points to the `role_id` of a *Contractor*.  This results in the user having *Contractor* privileges.

Also, within the event I need to assign the user to a *Supervisor*.  However, there is no *Supervisor* model.  Supervisors are also stored in the user table and have a role of *Supervisor* assigned to them.

**How can I create a relationship between *Contractors* and *Supervisors*?**

Ideally, i'd like to use something like this to create the Contractor/Supervisor relationship in the pivot table:

```
$user->supervisors()->save($supervisors, ['cust_id' => $event->user->cust_id]);
```

But i'm not sure how to setup my model...?

```
/**
 * The supervisors that belong to the user.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function supervisors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('SimplyTimesheets\Models\User\User')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your asking is possible, however your relationship model would look like this:

```
public function cands()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Some\Model')->where('something', $something)->where('something', $something); 
}
```

You would have to use where clauses to hard code a relationship between contractors and supervisors because there is no direct relationship between them both.

/*** Edit ***/

From your comment, you would have to approach that query with `eager loading` your relationship like so:

`User::has('supervisors')->join(...)->where(...)->get();`

The query above would return all users which meet the roles criteria. If you was just after one result you could create a `hasOne` relationship with your where clauses.

```
public function relationship()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Your\User_Role\Model', 'foreign_key', 'other_key')->where('role_id', supervisor)->where('role_id', contractor)
}
```

It all comes down to your application needs.

Comment: Hi jake, this does happen to be a pretty large application so I would want to get this right from the outset. What would you suggest as a better database design?

Comment: @V4n1ll4 Apologies, I had a second look over your question and your database structure seems sound to me. IMO I would still go with the relationship I defined above. What you have there is a more specific relationship that filters out unnecessary data you don't need. The only thing I would be careful of is naming the method because eventually you will define more relationships like the one above. I think what you was asking for in your question was too much for Eloquent and you just need to define so extra rules to help it out :)

Comment: Do you think this would work in my `user` model: `$this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\User')->join('role_user','user.id','=','role_user.user_id')->groupBy('user.id')->withTimestamps()`

Comment: It depends on what you're wanting your query to do. I thought you was wanting a relationship between contractors and supervisors? This query would return all users with their role, meaning you would fetch administrators aswell?

Comment: Ok so if I add a where clause to the above like: `->where('role_user.role_id', 2)` it should work right?  The `role_id` of a supervisor is 2.

Comment: @V4n1ll4 Updated my answer for you.